# Wordpress 6 Block Custom HTML formats and inserts <br /> and removes some <p> and add some <p>

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg, wordpress-block-theme

Using the latest the greatest WordPress (6.2.2), my problem is simple.
I want Block Custom HTML to not touch my content at all. Yes I know Custom HTML may not meant for JS but ignoring the `<br>`s in JS, it even adds and removes some of the `<p>` from regular HTML.

Here's an example below; it removes the `<p>` from "container" then adds `<br />` to JS then adds some `<p>` in "modalid", just WTH??

I don't think it's a big ask for WP to provide some kinda of action/filter to let the system save as raw.

I tried;

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

and nothing changes. I do not think Block templates are going thru this filter.

Turning this;

```
<footer>
    <div id="modalid" class="modal">
        <center>
            <h5>content</h5>

            content content content content content content content content content content content content content contentinformation by contentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontent <br> <br>

            For more information about our privacy practices, please review our <a href="link">Privacy Policy</a>.
        </center>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
       <p>
            <a class="footer-link" href="link">bla</a> |
            <a class="footer-link" href="link">bla</a>
            | <a class="footer-link" rel="modal:open" href="#modalid" target="_blank">Please Sell My Information</a> <br>
            &copy; 2014 - 2023 BLA. All rights reserved.
        </p>
    </div>
</footer>

<p>
   
   <script>
      $('.bla').bla({
          dots: false,
          infinite: true,
          
      });
   </script>
</p>
```

into this

```
<footer>
    <div id="modalid" class="modal">
        <center>
            <h5>content</h5>

            <p>content content content content content content content content content content content content content contentinformation by contentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontent <br> <br></p>

            <p>For more information about our privacy practices, please review our <a href="link">Privacy Policy</a>.</p><br />
        </center>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
       
            <a class="footer-link" href="link">bla</a> |
            <a class="footer-link" href="link">bla</a>
            | <a class="footer-link" rel="modal:open" href="#modalid" target="_blank">Please Sell My Information</a> <br>
            &copy; 2014 - 2023 BLA. All rights reserved.
       
    </div>
</footer>

<p>
   
   <script><br />
      $('.bla').bla({<br />
          dots: false,<br />
          infinite: true,<br />
          
      });<br />
   </script>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can replicate the issue as described in WP 6.2.2, though it only seems to occur when using `Custom HTML` block in a `Template Part` in the `Site Editor` - not when editing a post/page.

If you add the same code in a post/page and publish/preview/edit it, the code including the JS code remains the same. If you save the working code block as a reusable block and insert it into a Template Part in Site Editor, the issue appears inside the Editor.

**Site Editor**
[image: Site Editor: Template Part: Footer]

My observation is that it's not actually changing the underlying code: if you publish the template, the HTML source is rendered as expected. The issue appears to purely be within the Site Editor when it renders HTML safely as HTML.

**Output**
[image: Published Template Part: Source]

The rendered HTML includes the code *as expected*, with no erroneous `<p>` or `<br />` present.

If you **remove** the `<script>...<script>` code, the rendering issue in the Site Editor is resolved.

Ideally, you should [enqueue](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) the JS code separately, even if it is "just a few lines". For custom HTML code that requires front-end JS, I would register a [block variation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-variations/) of the core `Custom HTML` to enable enqueuing the JS for when the block variation is used.